# Unix search command in entire folder

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need to search entire folder with two keywords, lets say **ball** and **bat**. The unix folder has 10k files in it. So I need to use a command to search the entire files in that folder which is having this two keywords. the search must be with file wise. The below command is used to search with the single file but rather i need to have search with entire folder with file wise.

```
grep [args] -e ball -e bat file1.xml
```

The above command tells me if this two keyword present in that file or not. But what i need is the files which are having these two keyword in a folder.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for grep option "-l, --files-with-matches -- Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. "? (combined either with `*` as file name or `-r .` for a recursive search of the directory and below)

Comment: @dratenik -  Yes, i need the file names in that folder. Consider if suppose that folder is having 1000 files and the above two keyword is present in only 45 files, then i need to have output as that 45 file names, is that makes sense?

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -e ball -e bat {} \;`

Comment: @WilliamPursell - The second command is printing all the files in output either it has or not. But consider the below command it gives me the output for ball, in this same command can i add /,|,& or any other way to add bat also ??

Comment: find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "ball" -ls

Answer (score 1):

`grep [args] -e ball -e bat file1.xml` will match if the file contains either `ball` or `bat`, which does not seem to be what you want.  If that is what you want, you could do:

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec grep -l -e ball -e bat {} \;
```

Where `$dir` is the root directory you want to search.  But if you want to find all the files that contain both words, you would need to do something different.  Perhaps:

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -q ball $1 && grep -q bat $1' _ {} \; -print
```

or

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -q ball $1 && grep -l bat $1' _ {} \;
```

Comment: @willliam - The second command is printing all the files in output either it has or not. But consider the below command it gives me the output for ball, in this same command can i add /,|,& or any other way to add bat also ??

Comment: find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i "ball" -ls

Answer (score 0):

If you do `grep -e ball -e bat *` inside that folder should work.

Comment: It is taking in or function but i need the output in and function. ie. it must display the file having those two keyword not like either one of that

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `-exec` steps:

```sh
find . -type f \
    -exec grep -q 'ball' {} \; \
    -exec grep -l 'bat' {} +
```

The first `-exec` step retains all files that contain `ball` – use `print` instead of the second `-exec` step to see what files that are.

The second `-exec` step lists the names of the files that contain `bat`, and because they have already been filtered to contain `ball`, the result is the list of files containing both.